# pasar valor de getElementById a variable de java

Tags: ajax

**Buenas espero que me puedan ayudar, lo que necesito es conseguir que este código guarde el valor en una variable y no el div, o alguna forma de pasar el valor del div a  una variable **

```
function tiempoReal()
    {   
        var ide_proyecto = "<?php echo $ide;?>";
        var tabla = $.ajax({                
            url:'./load_ajax/seg.php',
            type:'GET',
            data: "ide_proyecto="+ide_proyecto+",               
            async:false
        }).responseText;
        document.getElementById("seg").innerHTML = tabla;
    }
    setInterval(tiempoReal, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola podrías hacer algo como esto.

```
function tiempoReal()
    {   
        var ide_proyecto = "<?php echo $ide;?>";
        var tabla = $.ajax({                
            url:'./load_ajax/seg.php',
            type:'GET',
            data: "ide_proyecto="+ide_proyecto+",               
            async:false
        }).responseText;
       var valorTabla = tabla;
    }
    setInterval(tiempoReal, 500);

o 


function tiempoReal()
    {   
        var ide_proyecto = "<?php echo $ide;?>";
        var tabla = $.ajax({                
            url:'./load_ajax/seg.php',
            type:'GET',
            data: "ide_proyecto="+ide_proyecto+",               
            async:false
        }).responseText;
       return tabla;
    }
    setInterval(tiempoReal, 500);
```

luego lo llamas de esta manera

```
var valorTabla = tiempoReal();
```

Comment: intente esto con ambos pero no pude no se que hice mal ` <? $var = "<script>document.write(valorTabla);</script>";
  echo $var;
  ?>`